# Custom authDomain in firebase-admin SDK?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have been looking to the [firebase-admin SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthgeneratesigninwithemaillink) and the [discussions groups](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/1ayebmAb8ns) and can not find any tips to generate a signInWithEmailLink with my domain server-side.

Is it possible to custom the signIn link in **server-side** with my domain? Or is it just possible in [client app](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain)?

> Update the Callback URL with your identity provider to use your custom domain instead of the default domain. For example, change https://myproject.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler to https://auth.mycustomdomain.com/__/auth/handler.

This is my actual work around but I would prefer a cleanest solution.

```
let link = await getAuth().generateSignInWithEmailLink(email, actionCodeSettings);

if(link.startsWith("https://myproject.firebaseapp.com")) {
  link = link.replace("https://myproject.firebaseapp.com", process.env.AUTH_URL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the [templates page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/emails), click edit and then click "customize domain".
The advance of doing so is that it not only affects Firebase admin.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin, it works! As I was using an external email provider (Mailgun), I never thought [changing the action link URL in the google templates](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?authuser=0&hl=en#actionlink) (that I was not using) would be the solution.